# Simulating a given boolean expression in the form of circuits using Java

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java program that will take in a expression as an input string (of the form R1*R2 + R2*R3 ) and then display the corresponding circuit.

For ex: The output should be something like this
Add a resistor R1.
To its end, Add a resistor R2.

Start a new connection.
Add a resistor R2.
To its end, Add a resistor R3.

I will like to represent it in diagram, but first I will just like to realize it like the above for simplicity.... Please suggest an algorithm !!

Answer (score 3):

As I see it this involves solving two fairly non-trivial tasks:

1. You need to parse the expression. I bet you'd like to have parenthesized expressions as well, such as (R1+R2)*R3. This calls for using a proper *parser*. I'd recommend you to look into parser generators such as JFlex/JavaCup or ANTLR.
2. If you want to display it to the user in a sensible way, you need to lay out the components in two dimensions nicely. This is basically a graph-problem, which can be solved by existing libraries. Still, as I said, it may not be trivial to implement.